# Yii2 Form validation

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I just started my first web app with Yii2. Had some problem with active form validation.

In my Model class, i have a set of rule.

**`ProfileForm.php`**

```
class ProfileForm extends Model
{
    public $email;
    public $lastName;
    public $firstName;
    public $password;
    public $phone;
    public $address;

    public function rules()
        {
            return [
                [['email', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'address'], 'required'],
            ];
        }
```

**`UserController`**

```
public function actionUpdateProfile()
{
    $model = new ProfileForm();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
        $user = User::findOne(Yii::$app->user->id);
        if ($user != NULL) {
            $user->email = $model->email;
            $user->firstName = $model->firstName;
            $user->lastName = $model->lastName;
            $user->address = $model->address;
            $user->phone = $model->phone;
            $user->save();
        }
    }   
}

public function actionProfile()
{
        $model = User::findOne(Yii::$app->user->id);
        return $this->render('profile', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]); 
}
```

view **`profile.php`**

```
<?php
    $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id' => 'profile-form',
        'action' => ['user/update-profile'],
        'options' => [],
        'fieldConfig' => [],
    ]);
?>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">First Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'firstName')->textInput([
            'placeholder' => $model->attributeLabels()['firstName']
            ])->label(false) ?>
    </div>
</div>
..
..
..
..
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
        <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Updated'), ['class' => 'btn btn-default', 'name' => 'profile-button']) ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

I want `ProfileForm` model class to validate the value before updating the actual model class. But the form validation does not trigger when i inserted empty value to fields in the view class.

Comment: Do you mean client side validation or server side is not triggered?

Comment: client side validation

Comment: For start remove `options' => [], 'fieldConfig' => []`

Comment: you can also change the manual assignment of all the fields from `Profile` to `User` in a single line i.e `$user->attributes=$model->attributes`

Comment: @Yupik removing that does not work.

Comment: What happens when you have field defined like: `<?= $form->field($model, 'firstName'); ?>`? And is something in browser console? Any error?

Comment: add `$form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id' => 'profile-form','enableClienValidation'=>true]);` would do it

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam it's enabled by default.

Comment: Where are u rendering your view file? :)

Comment: @mrateb updated on my controller.

Comment: are you sure that there are no errors on the `console` when you load the page and jquery is not loaded twice or `yii.activeForm` js file is present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling wrong model to `actionProfile()`:

```
public function actionProfile()
{
        $model = User::findOne(Yii::$app->user->id);  //here 
        return $this->render('profile', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]); 
}
```

You're calling `User::findOne()`, so you can't expect that **rules** from `ProfileForm` will work. If you wan't to use `ProfileForm`, you can extend your `User` model in `ProfileForm` class, like:

```
class ProfileForm extends User   // here your `User` model instead of `Model`
```

**^remember about namespaces^**

then change `actionProfile()` to:

```
public function actionProfile()
{
        $model = ProfileForm::findOne(Yii::$app->user->id);  //here ProfileForm now 
        return $this->render('profile', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]); 
}
```

==========================

Remember, if you're going to extend `User` by `ProfileForm` **you have to remove your attributes definitions**:

```
public $email;
public $lastName;
public $firstName;
public $password;
public $phone;
public $address;
```

Comment: I thought the problem was related to client-side validation not triggering and that won't affect even if you point the form's `action` to some other `controller/action` which does not even exist, but if the problem is validating after the form is submitted to the action then it may work.

Comment: Problem in fact **is** related to client-side validation. Client-side validation was using `User` model `rules()`, not `ProfileForm` model `rules()`, so if in `User` model there was not `require` rule on fields - it won't generate JS scripts to validate it.

Comment: ahh `:D` yeah right i didnt noticed that nice catch. +1 for that

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function actionUpdateProfile() {
        $model = ProfileForm::find()->where(['id' =>Yii::$app->user->id])->one();
        if (Yii::$app->request->post()) {
            $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
            if ($model->validate()) {
                $updateId = $model->update(Yii::$app->user->id)
            } 
        }
        return $this->render('profile', [
                    'model' => $model
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: First of all, this code have nothing to do with **client side validation**. Second - it's low quality code, you should refactor this when you can.

Comment: This Code is implemented in my form and properly validate.

Comment: Doesn't matter, i can write form with pure php in yii2, but still it's wrong, even if it's working. And, as i said, **this code have nothing to do with client side validation**.

Comment: @Yupik how can you say this code is nothing to do with client-side validation.Same code working in my file.

Comment: **Client side validation** is performed by a web browser (mostly by javascript). You pasted here controller action, with **server side validation**, with variable you don't use at all. Please **read OP question** and **comments** carefully again and focus on answer.

Comment: @RockyKumar the problem is with the frontend validation not being triggered on the fly if he hits the submit button with empty fields. and your code is not relevant  to that plus `$id` in your first line will be throwing an error, `Yii::$app->request->post()` should be `Yii::$app->request->isPost`, more over you can have a single check for `$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()`, then you should redirect instead of redring when successfully saved , and `Yii::$app->session->setFlash('validationError');` makes no sense

Comment: although I am not downvoting it you should either correct it and add a relevant answer or delete it, as you are likely to get more downvotes

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Thanks for the suggestion I appreciated it.